# Label not pining to the right of a tableview cell

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to pin the **points** label to the right of a tableview cell.

Problem is when I pin to the bottom, top and right and then I change the size of the screen, the pin doesn't work.

I have been watching loads of videos and articles about auto layout, and I really couldn't find out why it is not working.

This is how I setup the **Label 90** on a iPhone 8 screen

[image: iphone8]

So to achieve this I set these constraints

[image: constraints]

But when I change to an iPhone 8 Plus screen, this is the result, the **label 90** was dragged to the left

[image: iphone8plus]

And when I go back to iPhone 8 screen, the label is not even showing on the screen

[image: backtoiphone8]

Comment: This is happening in "PREVIEW" in Xcode or in Interface Editor? From where you are changing devices, can I see?

Comment: @ChatarVeerSuthar it is happening in both actually

Comment: where are you changing device from iPhone 8 to iPhone 8 Plus. Can I see that point so I understand it better

Comment: I suggest you to run app on simulator and see on UI Debugger, what your label has position and size, it will clear you that what should it be and where is mistake.

Comment: After running app on simulator you have to choose this option as in picture.

https://miro.medium.com/max/1148/1*N2ggjFeT41cWaqSAVKVN_Q.png

Comment: i'm using this configuration for my workspace. https://i.imgur.com/RGUebhd.png

Comment: Run the code and check debugger on simulator.

Comment: @ChatarVeerSuthar Weird thing is that I am running 2 simulators. One for iphone 8 and another one for iphone 8 plus and it looks right. But in the interface editor and preview looks wrong. Any idea?

Comment: Preview doesn't update run time constraints - The best is to use Preview for one device and its own preview. like iPhone 8 to iPhone 8. Otherwise better go for Running on Simulator/device to see accurate result of your constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraints seems to be right to see on all devices as you are keeping left (trailing) to 6, which is constant and will work same on all.

Please run on simulator, preview will only works better on same device to same preview, not otherwise as it doesn't do proper constraint like in run time.

Most important is to use UI debugger if any view is not placed well to get better idea where exactly the problem is.

Thanks.

Comment: I ran 3 simulators (iphone 8, iphone 8plus and ipad) and it was ok. It's unfortunate though that doesnt look good on editor.

Comment: I also suggest you to read more about multiplier, so you can adjust view in a way which get same perfection in all devices. @LeonardoD'Amato